# Keeping data in a UIViewController, even after go to a TablevViewController and come back?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with some UITextFields in it which holds username and other details. And i need to go to another view, which is a UITableView which holds the list of countries to user to choose and get back to the UIViewController again, when user picks one.

What my problem is i will lose all my data mentioned previously in the UIViewControl, when get back from UITableView. I can use application's delegate to store data when go to UITableView and load them back when UIViewController is loaded again.

I was wondering, whether is there a way to achieve my goal, other than this approach? I have to use number of variables in the delegate to store these data as there are many.

Can anyone help me out with an idea please???

Comment: Well you need to tell us a bit more. Most data in a viewcontroller is kept there, until the viewcontroller is unload. However if you use the viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload methods then when you push a view there is a change then the data get unload. This will happen when in the viewDidUnload method you reset the data (eq. relase an array).

Comment: How are you coming back to the earlier controller?

Comment: Hi rckoenes and Deepak, 
Thanks for the input and interest. Much appreciated. 
I think answering Deepak’s question might get clear things out. I am not using a UINavigationController (this is a View Based Application), so in order to get back I am using dismissModalViewController rather than popping a view from navigational stack. I am a very beginner of iPhone application development so, didn’t know of pushing and popping views in to navigational stack until yesterday.  Can I get mu answer using pushing and popping the view in to navigational stack?
I value your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think.But I think you are reloading the table in viewWillAppear.Thats why ur older values are not remaining

Comment: Hi Swastik,
Thanks for taking interest to answer my question.  My problem is not with the UITableView, but with the UIViewController . Means in this UIViewController I am talking about, there is a form with several fields which holds the values entered by user. I have a list of countries implemented on a UITableView also.
When the user hits a button in the UIViewController, UITableView will be shown and when user choose a country in the UITableView, focus should be get back in to UIViewController with **all the fields having the values entered by user previuosly.**

Comment: .... (cont'd from prev comment) My initial idea was to save all the data in delegate variables and re-populate the UIViewController when gets back. If I choose that approach, I need to store lots of data. So I am thinking of another way to achieve this. Can you please help me out, Swastik?